# Example of dependence with zero covariance

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, covariance, independence

This is a constructivist question.

**Please provide a bi-variate distribution or density/mass function of two absolutely continuous/discrete (but not mixed-type) random variables, which (may) have covariance zero and still be dependent.**
***But mind the constraints:*** The density/mass function should not have branches, i.e. each has to be a single mathematical expression for all the support of the distribution, where it is not zero. The same should hold for the marginal distributions. (In a parametric context, I guess the ideal will be to have a parameter governing covariance, and some other parameter(s) governing any other form of dependence, but "hard-wired" zero-covariance is ok for starters). And it would be preferable to avoid exotic supports.

**Notes:** It may be the case that this is trivially answered using the concept of **Copulas**. But we do want the marginals here. So any Copula-based answer I hope will be kind enough to explicitly provide also the marginals (or an example of marginals, if the answer provides a general mechanism of distributions-generation). Also, situations like e.g. a Bernoulli whose probability parameter is modeled as random and drawn from some other distribution, are not of interest here.

I am asking this and placing all these restrictions because to date, I find all examples of "zero covariance does not imply independence" absolutely true but artificial. I am thinking about situations where your "everyday" statistics practitioner (not necessarily a high-profile academic/professional) will be called upon to model -and most likely he will tend to try first some "smooth" representation. Does he have the theoretical modeling tools that will permit him to conclude "zero-covariance together with dependence"?

Naturally, I did try but have not yet found any such example -but this only attests to my knowledge gaps, not to whether such bi-variate distributions are hard to find. Meaning, any literature references are also welcome.

Comment: $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y=X*(-1)^\xi$, where $\xi\in Bernoulli(1/2)$. $X$ and $Y$ are [dependent but uncorrelated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent).

Comment: @Aksakal That belongs to the "well-known and artificial examples". What is their joint distribution?

Comment: These constraints seem highly artificial, even to practitioners. They would rule out things like Gamma distributions, for instance (which are not necessarily smooth at $0$ and require a "branch" to describe the negative part). Since copulas automatically apply to *any* marginal, your objections to their use are hard to fathom. You might have gotten lost in the abstractions. If you have a particular statistical problem where you would like a model that incorporates bivariate distributions having no necessary relationship between covariance and independence, then why not provide that context?

Comment: What is the point you are making here? Is it that in practice if there's no correlation, then there's no dependence? Otherwise, what's the problem with "artificial" distributions?

Comment: @Aksakal I am not _making a point_.  I ask for examples of distributions that can be used without being constructed for the purpose -the same way we have available a menu of widely known and studied marginal distributions that are handy to start the attempt to model some phenomenon.

Comment: All widely known distributions were constructed for some purpose. What is your *purpose*? What are you trying to model here?

Comment: @whuber I do not object to a Copula-answer. But exactly because they apply to any marginal, I just noted that it would be nice if an answer "Copula named XX does provide zero-covariance together with other forms of dependence" also contained an example "so assume that the underlying marginals are so and so, therefore etc".

Comment: @Aksakal Any relation between two random variables with zero-covariance and at the same time other forms of dependence. Why should it be more specific? We are talking about theoretical tools here. So any such example will do.

Comment: It should be more specific, because it's unclear why don't you like the well-known example to which I referred. You called "artificial", yet you don't seem to have any particular phenomenon in mind. It's shown many times that dependence does not always manifest in correlation. It's an important observation for anyone who models anything

Comment: @Aksakal In the example, $Y$ is not specified as "identically distributed with $X$ or its negative" -it is specified as _being_ $X$ or its negative. This would correspond to  two-dimensional data sets where in each realization-pair the one value is exactly equal or the negative of the other value in the pair. I have not encountered such data sets.

Comment: This question still seems vague and purposeless. If you would like a demonstration of how vast the possibilities are, take *any* two independent random variables $(U,V)$ having a common variance and let $X=U+V$, $Y=U-V$. $X$ and $Y$ have zero covariance, but usually are not independent (bivariate Normal $(U,V)$ being a notable exception). The dependence is particularly obvious when the range of either $U$ or $V$ has a bound (upper, lower, or both). Yet, whenever the PDF of $(U,V)$ has any "nice" mathematical form, so does the PDF of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: @whuber Once more I get the feeling that my questions are not a good match with CV. That's unfortunate, but I will have to accept it, and stop asking them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to: you have asked a bunch of highly upvoted questions, so I see no evidence of a general pattern of "not a good match." This particular question, though, seems unlikely to be received well because it's so hard to pin down what it's really trying to ask and you quickly shot down what looked (and still looks) like a perfectly good and insightful answer.

Comment: @whuber I could "fake" my question as follows : "I have a two-dimensional data set and I need to model it into a bivariate density. Sample covariance is essentially zero, but I have reasons to believe that the two  continuous RVs are not-independent. Can you provide some examples for a bivariate density that exhibits zero-covariance but also some other form of dependence? Preferably some "simple" form because I am not too experienced in dealing with densities with branches and things like that. Also, if you propose a Copula, please provide some details since I am not very familiar with them".

Comment: That's getting there. It's still pretty broad, though. You should anticipate comments asking you what you know about the nature of the dependence. Although it's ok to say you're not willing to assume anything, you would be putting a burden on respondents to suggest some large and flexible distribution family that is sufficient to handle a huge variety of situations, and that is going to lead to semi-parametric or non-parametric tests. At that point, a practitioner with a *real* problem would probably want to learn more about the situation and hope to adopt a parametric model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Among spherically symmetric distributions, i.e. distributions of the form $f(\boldsymbol x) = \varphi(\|\boldsymbol x\|)$ where $f$ is the density with respect to Lebesgue measure, it can be shown that the coordinates always have zero correlation, essentially due to the fact that the distribution is invariant under orthogonal transformations. This family includes, for example, the multivariate normal distribution, but also things like the multivariate t distribution.

It can be shown that, in fact, the multivariate normal is the **only** spherically symmetric distribution with independent components. Now, spherical symmetry is in fact a *very reasonable* property that a statistician might expect a distribution to have in some settings. *Hence, inferring independence of components from no correlation makes very strong assumptions about the tails of the distribution in this case*!

See for example [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2984955?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). See [this report](http://aurelie.boisbunon.free.fr/downloads/loisSS.pdf) for more on the properties of spherically symmetric distributions.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. The main point of my question is that I would like to be able to infer exactly the opposite ("zero-covariance but still dependent"), in a tangible way. I am looking into the references now.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings True. But I was very young four years ago...

Answer (score 0):

The last row of the first image of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence provide exemple where the Pearson correlation is 0 but there is strong non-linear dependance between X and Y.

The relation $\rho=0$ is quite strong in general but easily obtainable considering discrete and / or symetrical distributions. That's why you usually end up with discrete / symmetrical distribution as exemples. The article provide an exemple of an assymetrical distribution (but discrete). A sum of three gaussian centered on the three points should yield the same result.

In the real life the symmetry could arise from the set-up of the problem as evoked above. More rarely it could arise from an assymetrical setup, that just happen to give a 0 correlation.